# Из-за регистрации и вставки зоны виджетов Wordpress изменилась верстка

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка, виджет

Уважаемые эксперты Stack Overflow! При натяжке самодельной темы html/css на движок Wordpress (страница: http://www.lifetree.angliskiyprosto.com/) нужно было вставить зоны виджетов в три колонки над футером:

```
<div class="colonka"><div class="s1"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/img/predv_veshaniya.jpg"></div>Знакомство с авторским тренингом "Древо Жизни" Алексея Маматова<div class="ljh1"><?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>

    <div id="sidebar-1" class="ljh1">

        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>

    </div>

<?php endif; ?><button class="w1">Заказать
</button></div></div>
```

После регистрации и вставки php колонки сползли вниз, а над ценами и кнопками "Купить" появилась черная точка. В первоначальных стилях такие значения не заданы:

```
.ljh1 {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    padding-top: 43%;


}

.ljh1 p {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Может быть дело в том, как я зарегистрировал зону виджетов в functions.php:

```
<?php
function twentynineteen_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'          => __( 'Footer', 'twentynineteen' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
            'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your footer.', 'twentynineteen' ),

        )
    );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentynineteen_widgets_init' );
?>
```

Comment: Можешь открыть например инструменты разработчика и посмотреть что там у тебя

Comment: <li id="text-2" class="widget widget_text">   <div class="textwidget"><p>1000000 руб.</p>
</div>
  </li>   Действительно, появился какой-то маркировочный список

Comment: с какими-то свойствами, которые я нигде не вставлял.. li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}\

Comment: Все равно, честно говоря, не понял, как решить проблему..

Answer (score 1):

Читаем параметры функции [register_sidebar()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_sidebar). А конкретно вот этот кусок:

> before_widget(строка) HTML код, который будет расположен перед каждым
>   виджетом в панели. Например: . Конструкции %1$s
>   и %2$s будут заменены на id и class используемого в сайдбаре виджета.
>
> По умолчанию: `<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">`

Та же история и с `after_widget`

Примерно так решается проблема:

```
 register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'          => __( 'Footer', 'twentynineteen' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
            'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your footer.', 'twentynineteen' ),
            'before_widget' => '',
            'after_widget'  => '',

        )
    );
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо за помощь и уделенное время! Черная точка над вставленным виджетом ушла после text-decoration: none к блоку, обрамляющему php код виджета + li, то есть .blockclass li { ... Если добавть в sidebar больше виджетов, то каждый из них будет с точкой, оказывается, автоматически добавляется маркировочный список..